# How to erase the dotted watermark from set of similar images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0, watermark

I want to automate the task of entering set of images into a number generating system & before that i like to remove a dotted watermark which is common across these images.

I tried using google, tesseract & abby reader, but I found that the image part that does not contain the watermark is recognized well, but the part that is watermarked is almost impossible to recognize.

I would like to remove the watermark using image processing. I already tried few sample codes of opencv, python, matlab etc but none matching my requirements...

Here is a sample code in Python that I tried which changes the brightness & darkness:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("d:\\Docs\\WFH_Work\\test.png")
alpha = 2.5
beta = -250
new = alpha * img + beta
new = np.clip(new, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("my window", new)
```

Unusually, i dont know the watermark of this image consists how many pixels. Is there a way to get rid of this watermark OR make digits dark and lower the darkness of watermark via code?

Here is watermarked image

[image]

Comment: You've tried stuff "...etc but none matching my requirements..."; we do not want to fall short either: Please be more specific with your requirements, by either posting a cleaned image that you find acceptable, or post the code that generates images not meeting your requirements, so we can calibrate our answers.

Comment: Hi Reblochon Masque, I updated the post with more info, pls take a look and suggest further

Answer (score 0):

I am using `dilate` to remove the figures, then find the edge to detect watermark. Remove it by main gray inside watermark

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('test.png', 0)

kernel = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)

dilation = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 1) 
erosion = cv2.erode(dilation,kernel,iterations = 1)


plt.imshow(erosion, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

#contour
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(erosion, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

plt.imshow(edged, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Phước Hữu Lưu, 
I tried yr code and along with the image you shared, here is the link of other image produced by plt.show() https://imgur.com/yj0Zsfd ...still Im unclear about how to proceed to get result, could you kindly share final code for the image where I can use Ocr on image without watermark?